# Explicitly remove left outer join while creating hibernate query

Tags: hibernate

I have a hbm file, which defines the left outer join.
Now, I need to create a query which does not require any left outer join.

Please help me, what criteria should I use to explicitly remove left outer join while creating hibernate query, which is already defined in hbm file.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you have a named query defined, and want to execute a query that is similar to this named query, but still different. The solution is simply to not use this named query. Define another one, doing what you want it to do, and use this new named query instead of the other one.

Or, if you don't want to repeat all the common stuff between both queries, don't use named queries at all, and compose the query dynamically, directly in your Java code.

Comment: Thanks JB. Basically I am using hibernate template and criteria to create and execute query. So, is there any way to remove left outer join using hibernate query, once join is defined in the hbm & dto class?

Comment: It's hard to understand anything without code, but I would say no.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using left outer join for eagar fetching of object then, would suggest remove left outer join and define hibernate fetch profile, have a look [doc](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/reference/en/html/performance.html#performance-fetching-profiles)